# Pass a Model from a Controller to a View MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC and created a view with Entity. I have been looking for the last day how to pass a model from controller to a view. I see that when they gonna send a model back to the view they do it with `return view(model);`, but every time I try returning a model all the textbox are empty and nothing happens. I am trying to fill 40 Textbox that's the reason I am trying to use a model if there is a better way to do this.

HTML:

```html
@model SiCom.Data.TransComm 
@{ ViewBag.Title = "ManualAdvancements"; }

<h2>ManualAdvancements</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Master_Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Master_Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Master_Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ManualAdvancements(TransComm model, string submit, FormCollection form)
{
    string Paramater = form["Paramater"].ToString();
    int Parameter2= int.Parse(form["Parameter2"].ToString());
    string Paramater3= form["Paramater3"].ToString();
    model = Data.SiComData.GetSingleTransCom(Paramater, Parameter2, Paramater3);
    return View(model);
}
```

After all, the view is still Empty. 
Any Help will be apricieted.

Comment: Start by using the debugger to inspect the data in the model being passed to the view (from the controller). Does it contain the data you expect?

Comment: Yes, I debug de model and it always comes full

Comment: @RafaelRamirez, Provide the model, please.

Comment: @d_petrishin the model is created with Entityframework from a database table. still want me to preview the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `ModelState.Clear()` before returning the model to the view.

Answer (score -2):

I cant see anything wrong in your code snip.
Only thing I would say is -

1. Ensure that your model in the controller file(and in the method) in this line is not NULL

model = Data.SiComData.GetSingleTransCom(Paramater, Parameter2, Paramater3);
return View(model);

2. Other thing is in the View fist line should have
   @model Fully.Qualified.Namespace.ModelName

Hope it helps you....

Comment: The model name doesn't have to be fully qualified in the view. It depends on what namespaces have been imported.

Comment: This sort of remark should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Of course I tried to use the comment. Did you not know that users with score of 50 or less the comments feature is disabled for the main Question? BTW thanks for improving my score..much appreciated.!